# Set default font family for TinyMCE HTMLFiled()

Tags: django, tinymce

I have set default font family "Sofia Sans" in < body > tag for all templates in custom.css but when I paste a text with different font family in the Django Admin TinyMCE HTMLFiled() it overrides the default font.
Is it posible to set default font family for the HTMLFiled() to be "Sofia Sans" no matter what the copied text font is?

Answer (score 0):

Create format.py file with format_font() function that force formating all the css font-family properties when called:

```
import re


def format_font(text, font='font-family: "Sofia Sans", sans-serif;'):
    regex = '(?s)font-family:(.*?);'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)

    return re.sub(pattern, font, text)
```

Than in the view call the format_font() to fotmat the output of the HTMLField (general_page_obj.text):

```
def general_page(request):

    general_page_obj = GeneralPage.objects.get()    
    general_page_obj.text = format_font(general_page_obj.text)

    return render(request, 'pages/general_page.html', {'general_page': general_page_obj}
```